# Delphi - open source projects

Tags: delphi, open-source

I want to get involved in open source projects written in Delphi. Until now I know about project JEDI and CNPack groups. Do you know other open source projects/communities? I would really appreciate if the answer comes from a member of that community.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Go to the [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=delphi), search for Delphi, choose the project and ask coordinator to join to the project.
2. You can participate in [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/) project. There is **a lot** of different directions, responsibilities, platforms, etc.
3. Go to the [EMBT job forum](https://forums.embarcadero.com/forum.jspa?forumID=18), post there message, that you are available for open source project written in Delphi and wait for responses.
4. Start you own project :)

Answer (score 6):

There are around **823** open source project for Delphi hosted on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3adelphi)
you browse and find which one you interested more.

here are two projects just came to my mind :

[Delphi Spring Framework](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-spring-framework/)

[Delphi On Rails](http://code.google.com/p/delphionrails/)

Answer (score 6):

Not quite Delphi, but close enough that you might be interested:

Have a look at the FreePascal project ( http://www.freepascal.org/ ), and its associated Delphi-like IDE Lazarus ( http://lazarus.freepascal.org/ ).

It's not entirely 100% Delphi compatible, but it is very close in terms of being able to import and use Delphi source code.

In addition, there are stacks of open source applications written using Lazarus, as well as a bunch of IDE extensions.

Definitely worth a try if you're interested in Delphi.

Answer (score 4):

GExperts ([Homepage](http://www.gexperts.org/)/[Discussion](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/GExpertsDiscuss/)) has lots of possibilities to get involved.

Answer (score 1):

The [TurboPower](https://sourceforge.net/users/tpsfadmin) projects are all open source, and progress has been slow from lack of developers.  Pretty much any position (code, documentation, web sites) is available, and there's a bunch that aren't being actively maintained if you want to try admining one.  The downside is that since they haven't had many updates since they went open source the communities are fairly small.

[I'm](https://sourceforge.net/users/capeterson) admin for [Abbrevia](http://tpabbrevia.sourceforge.net/) (zip/tar/gz/cab archives).  [Roman Kassebaum](https://sourceforge.net/users/romankassebaum/) takes care of [Orpheus](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tporpheus/) (visual controls) and [OnGuard](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tponguard/) (creates demo apps).  Sean Durkin is handling [LockBox](http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/tiki-index.php) (encryption) and [Async Pro](http://tpapro.sourceforge.net/) (serial communications).  It looks like [Sebastian Zierer](https://sourceforge.net/users/benji) is updating [XML Partner](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tpxmlpartner/).

Answer (score 1):

Arguably the most popular Delphi open source project is the Indy Project.  http://www.indyproject.org/index.en.aspx

Comment: And to satisfy Radu's request, I am a member of that project.

Answer (score 1):

Components for connecting database

[Zeos](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/)

[UIB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uib/files/)

Answer (score 0):

[Multiplatform screenshot taking utility](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=622827#622827)

Application goals:

- Support Windows and MAC;
- Take screenshot of whole desktop, active window, selected area;
- Record desktop activity and save as AVI;
- Load video, extract selected/random frames, save as image;
- Upload screenshot image to Imageshack, etc.
- etc...